# Azure Digital Twins and Tenants

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Seems that in this preview version I can have only one Azure Twin instance running on my Subscription.

How do I roll it out to customers? I have to create on instance of Azure Twins at they own subscription?

Regards,
Emerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [limit per subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-service-limits#per-instance-limits) will be removed when Azure Digital Twins goes into General Availability. That date has not been announced yet as far as I know. Although you could use the preview version in a production environment for your customers, the functionalities of the public preview might change.

You are right to say if you need to roll this out to customers you would need a separate subscription for each instance.